# Adding two column values in SQL Server to populate a third column, can this be done without a trigger/stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a very specific question regarding this. I know I can use `SUM` to sum the values of the two columns, however, there are some other requirements that need to be handled other than just running a basic query.

1. A third column needs to be present in the table which will contain the value of the two columns.
2. This third column needs to be updated whenever a row is created or either of the two values in the other columns are updated.

Can this be done by setting a default value in the column with some sort of reference to update whenever either of the other two columns are updated?  That would be the easiest solution. Or, do I need a trigger/stored procedure combination that will fire and run whenever a row is created or one of those two columns is updated?  If so, how would I go about implementing that?

This is the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[haems_callLog]
(
    [month] [int] NOT NULL,
    [year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_haems_callLog_total]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [station] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_haems_callLog_station]  DEFAULT (N'-'),
    [station1_Total] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_haems_callLog_station1_total]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [station2_Total] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_haems_callLog_station2_total]  DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The total fields default to "0". At the creation of a record, only the month, year, station, and either the `station1_Total` or `station2_Total` columns will be fed data. The total column then needs to take the value of either `station1_Total` or `station2_Total` and in addition to the "0" default of the other column be populated with the summed value.

When a record is updated, either of those two columns could be changed, which then needs to be reflected in the summed value in the total column.

Thanks in advance for the help and guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a **computed column** like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[haems_callLog]
ADD GrandTotal AS [station1_Total] + [station2_Total] PERSISTED
```

This adds a new column, which will always reflect the sum of those two other columns - no matter what those columns contain. This new computed column is always updated if any of the two underlying columns gets updated.